# Fresh React Native Project Fails on IOS 15 build only when archiving and on local device (M1 MacBook)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios15

I am using the latest react-native version 66.4 I think. The app works fine in the simulator (ios 15) when building, but as soon as I switch to build on my local device or when I want to archive the following error appears:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

at here:

Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$NODE_BINARY" $NODE_ARGS "$CLI_PATH" $BUNDLE_COMMAND $CONFIG_ARG --entry-file "$ENTRY_FILE" --platform "$BUNDLE_PLATFORM" --dev $DEV --reset-cache --bundle-output "$BUNDLE_FILE" --assets-dest "$DEST" $EXTRA_ARGS $EXTRA_PACKAGER_ARGS
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I don't think this is even a M1 related issue, but it is weird that it only occurs outside of the simulator. Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same not really sure but other colleagues without M1 are able to run the same project